# Python script to get line numbers of lines starting with a special character without reading the whole file

Tags: python, file, file-io

I have a big file, and I'd like to get the line numbers of the lines that start with the character `>`. Is there a way to do this without going through the file line by line?

Comment: Do you mean *"without reading the whole file **at the same time**"*, or *"without reading the whole file **at all**"* ? If it is the latter, the answer is obviously no.

Comment: Are you looking for Python answers only? If you are using Linux then this can probably be achieved using shell commands and will also most likely be faster.

Comment: @DeepSpace yeah that's what I figured. I have to go line by line. I don't know if I get line numbers with grep first, and then used the seek functions it would be faster. But eventually I need to do everything from the python side. Even run shell commands through python, if that's faster.

Comment: How large of a file are we talking about here? have you tried to benchmark the naive `for n, line in enumerate(file, 1): if line.startswith('>'): line_nums.append(n)` solution?

Comment: @DeepSpace currently, ~5G. It doesn't take horribly long, so it's fine, but I was asking more out of curiosity. I guess if I had much larger files I could or should use something like spark.

Comment: Do you need the actual line numbers or (since you mentioned seeking) just the byte offsets of lines starting with ">"? The latter might be easier to do efficiently.